# How to decrypt the encrypted string coming from python?

Tags: ios, swift, python-2.7, aes, pycrypto

I get a encrypted base64 string from python. The format is AES 256 CBC. But when I try to decrypt using iOS Swift it return decrypted string as nil.

```
# coding=utf-8
import base64
from random import choice
from string import letters

try:
    from Crypto import Random
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
except ImportError:
    import crypto
    import sys

    sys.modules['Crypto'] = crypto
    from crypto.Cipher import AES
    from crypto import Random


class AESCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.bs = 32
        self.key = key

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        _raw = raw
        raw = self._pad(raw)

        print raw, ';'
        print _raw, ';'

        iv = "".join([choice(letters[:26]) for i in xrange(16)])
        print " iv :", iv
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:AES.block_size]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return self._unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[AES.block_size:])).decode('utf-8')

    def _pad(self, s):
        a = (self.bs - len(s) % self.bs)
        b = chr(self.bs - len(s) % self.bs)
        return s + a * b

    @staticmethod
    def _unpad(s):
        return s[:-ord(s[len(s) - 1:])]
def encrypt(k, t):
    o = AESCipher(k)
    return o.encrypt(t)


def decrypt(k, t):
    o = AESCipher(k)
    return o.decrypt(t)


def main():
    k = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwerty"
    s1 = "Hello World!"

    d2 = encrypt(k, s1)

    print " Password :", k
    print "Encrypted :", d2
    print "    Plain :", decrypt(k, d2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## iOS

Here I use AES256CBC Lib https://github.com/SwiftyBeaver/AES256CBC

```
let decrypted = AES256CBC.decryptString("Ymdqc3ZqdmZ1cXdsZG1sZenhgr4Xt0+ceARYRh1n40QkNDV/dyKbQjYLcbiXBBeO", password: "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwerty")

        print("decrypted: \(String(describing: decrypted))") // here I get nil
```

when python run I get this Logs

```
iv : bgjsvjvfuqwldmle
 Password : qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwerty
Encrypted : Ymdqc3ZqdmZ1cXdsZG1sZenhgr4Xt0+ceARYRh1n40QkNDV/dyKbQjYLcbiXBBeO
    Plain : Hello World!
```

I don't know why python and iOS not same in AES. Anyone solve this issue please put answer below. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to decode your base64 string first.
Maybe this will work (just googled it, I'm not a iOS dev, so I'm sorry to eventual errors)

```
let decodedData = NSData("Ymdqc3ZqdmZ1cXdsZG1sZenhgr4Xt0+ceARYRh1n40QkNDV/dyKbQjYLcbiXBBeO": base64String, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let decrypted = AES256CBC.decryptString(decodedString, password: "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwerty")
        print("decrypted: \(String(describing: decrypted))")
```

It's also stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/SwiftyBeaver/AES256CBC)

Comment: Actually what is the difference between my code and your code?

Comment: The ciphertext: `bgjsvjvfuqwldmleYmdqc3ZqdmZ1cXdsZG1sZenhgr4Xt0+ceARYRh1n40QkNDV/dyKbQjYLcbiXBBeO` is concatenation of the initialization vector (`bgjsvjvfuqwldmle`) and the encrypted blocks of your message (`Ymdqc3ZqdmZ1cXdsZG1sZenhgr4Xt0+ceARYRh1n40QkNDV/dyKbQjYLcbiXBBeO`).

Comment: Thats okey, But I don't know how to utilise your ideas because I am beginner in iOS. Can you test for me.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong! I didn't see that you already prepend the IV to the remaining encrypted message here `base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))`. I'm looking for the real problem.

Comment: Python dev. Reading AES256CBC's documentation I've found that it look for the first 16 characters of the string to extract the IV. Base64 encodings expands each 3 bytes of the plaintext into 4 bytes, so, if you have a 64 bytes (`Ymdqc3ZqdmZ1cXdsZG1sZenhgr4Xt0+ceARYRh1n40QkNDV/dyKbQjYLcbi‌​XBBeO`), the decoded plaintext would be 48 bytes length (16bytes for the IV and 32bytes for the encrypted block). I think you need to the decode your string from base64 to raw first.

Comment: Which is nil? `decodedData`, `decodedString`, or `decrypted`?

Comment: I get the base64 String I try to decode so I get nil in decode. Then I use that to decrypt, the decryption get nil also. These are work inside the lib. Now I noticed through breakpoints

Comment: Hang on, I'm trying to install swift to try it :)

Comment: No way to get this work with swift for linux :( Have you done any progress?

Comment: Oh I use mac. https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl This is a an online tool for compile swift.